# Sequence of order statistic converges to median?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, order-statistics, law-of-large-numbers, median

Suppose that $(X_1,...,X_N)$ be $N$ iid samples from uniform distribution. Let $X_{(n)}$ be $n$-th order statistic. It sounds natural that $X_{N/2}$ converges to the median, $1/2$. (interpret $N/2$ as the largest integer which does not exceed $N/2$). 
More generally, given continuous distribution $F$ with support $[a,b]$ and $\alpha\in (0,1)$, can we show that $X_{(\alpha N)}$ converges to $F^{-1}(\alpha)$ in probability, or distribution, or almost sure?

Answer (score 2):

Let $U_i\sim \mathcal{U}(0,1)$

The distribution of the $N\alpha$ order statistic from a uniform distribution has a standard beta distribution ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic)). Specifically:

$U_{(\alpha N)}\sim B(N\alpha,N-N\alpha+1)$

For reference, if $T\sim B(a,b)$ then $E[T]=\frac{a}{a+b}\;\; Var[T]=\frac{ab}{(a+b)^2(a+b-1)}$

Therefore, $E[U_{(\alpha N)}]=\mu_{\alpha,N}=\frac{\alpha N}{N+1}$ and $Var[U_{(\alpha N)}]=\frac{\alpha N(N-\alpha N +1)}{N(N+1)^2} = \sigma^2_{\alpha,N}$

Using [Chebyshev's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality):

$P(|U_{(\alpha N)}-\mu_{\alpha,N}]\geq \epsilon|\leq \frac{\sigma^2_{\alpha,N}}{\epsilon^2}$

and the fact that $\lim\limits_{N\to \infty} \mu_{\alpha,N} = \alpha$ and $\lim\limits_{N\to \infty}\sigma^2_{\alpha,N} = 0 $

That $\forall \epsilon \exists N: P(|U_{(\alpha N)}-\mu_{\alpha,N}]\geq \epsilon|\leq \frac{\sigma^2_{\alpha,N}}{\epsilon^2}$, hence 
$U_{(\alpha N)} \xrightarrow{p} \alpha$

Can we show something stronger? To show almost sure convergence, we need to demonstrate that excursions of size $\epsilon>0$ from $\alpha$ do not occur infinitely often ([via Borel-Cantelli lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma)) and that this holds for arbitrarily small $\epsilon$.

Specifically, we need to define a sequence of events $A_n$ such that $\sum P(A_n)<\infty$, which implies that only finitely many of the $A_n$ occur. If we define $A_N(\epsilon_N,\alpha):= |U_{\alpha N}-\alpha|>\epsilon_N$ where $\epsilon_N>0$ and $\epsilon_N \to 0$ monotonically, what is the probability that this occurs infinitely often?

Let $P(A_N(\epsilon_N,\alpha))=P_{B(N\alpha,N-N\alpha+1)}(\{\alpha-\epsilon_N>U_{N\alpha}\}\cup\{U_{N\alpha}>\alpha+\epsilon_N\})$, where $P_{B(N\alpha,N-N\alpha+1)}(\cdot)$ is the cdf of a standard beta distribution.

The trick is to define a sequence of decreasing errors such that the limit of the errors is 0 and $\sum P(A_N(\epsilon_N,\alpha)) <\infty$

I played around with various exponentially decreasing errors (to avoid the high errors in the beginning) but didn't have much luck. You'll need some heavier theory than I know to prove one way or the other.

**New Info**

I thought of trying a different approach by examining the convergence of the empirical distribution function to the true distribution function. It turns out that the ECDF converges *almost surely* to the CDF, therefore, sample percentiles converge almost surely to their true percentiles. [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function).

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but here is a complete answer to it.

Actually this is true for any distribution and not necessarily for uniform distribution. Assume that $F^{-1}(\alpha)$ is well defined. That is, in a sufficiently small neighbourhood of $\alpha$, $F$ is strictly increasing and $F^{-1}(\alpha)$ is uniquely defined. But one also needs to be careful and say $X_{(\lfloor \alpha N\rfloor)}$.

Define the empirical cdf $\displaystyle F_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbf{1}_{\{X_{n}\leq x\}}$ .

Now notice that $nF_{n}(x)\geq k\iff x_{(k)}\leq x $

\begin{align}P(X_{(\lfloor \alpha N\rfloor)}-F^{-1}(\alpha)>\epsilon)&=
1-P(X_{(\lfloor \alpha N\rfloor)}-F^{-1}(\alpha)\leq \epsilon)\\
&=1-P(X_{(\lfloor \alpha N\rfloor)}\leq F^{-1}(\alpha)+\epsilon)\\
&=1-P\bigg(NF_{N}(F^{-1}(\alpha)+\epsilon)\geq \lfloor \alpha N\rfloor\bigg)\\
&=1-P\bigg(F_{N}(F^{-1}(\alpha)+\epsilon)\geq\frac{\lfloor \alpha N\rfloor}{N}\bigg)\\
&=P\bigg(F_{N}(F^{-1}(\alpha)+\epsilon)<\frac{\lfloor \alpha N\rfloor}{N}\bigg)\end{align}

Now $F_{N}(x)$ converges to $F(x)$ by Strong Law of Large Numbers almost surely for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$

Now $F_{N}(F^{-1}(\alpha)+\epsilon)\xrightarrow{P} F(F^{-1}(\alpha)+\epsilon)$ and so $F_{N}(F^{-1}(\alpha)+\epsilon)-F(F^{-1}(\alpha)+\epsilon)\xrightarrow{P}0$

Now \begin{align}&P\bigg(F_{N}(F^{-1}(\alpha)+\epsilon)<\frac{\lfloor \alpha N\rfloor}{N}\bigg)\\&=P\bigg(F_{N}(F^{-1}(\alpha)+\epsilon)-F(F^{-1}(\alpha)+\epsilon)<\frac{\lfloor \alpha N\rfloor}{N}-F(F^{-1}(\alpha)+\epsilon)\bigg)\end{align}

But we have that $\frac{\lfloor \alpha N\rfloor}{N}\to \alpha$ and due to the strictly increasing assumption, $F^{-1}(F(\alpha)+\epsilon)>F^{-1}(F(\alpha))=\alpha$. Thus for all $N$ large enough $\frac{\lfloor \alpha N\rfloor}{N}-F(F^{-1}(\alpha)+\epsilon)<-\delta$ for some $\delta>0$

Hence, \begin{align}&P\bigg(F_{N}(F^{-1}(\alpha)+\epsilon)-F(F^{-1}(\alpha)+\epsilon)<\frac{\lfloor \alpha N\rfloor}{N}-F(F^{-1}(\alpha)+\epsilon)\bigg)\\&\leq P\bigg(F_{N}(F^{-1}(\alpha)+\epsilon)-F(F^{-1}(\alpha)+\epsilon)<-\delta\bigg)\xrightarrow{N\to \infty} 0\end{align}

Similarly, one shows that $P(X_{(\lfloor \alpha N\rfloor)}-F^{-1}(\alpha)\leq-\epsilon)\xrightarrow{N\to\infty}0$.

This proves that $X_{(\lfloor \alpha N\rfloor)}\xrightarrow{P}F^{-1}(\alpha)$

Now $X_{(\lfloor \alpha N\rfloor)}$ has a subsequence that converges almost surely to $F^{-1}(\alpha)$ . But then, as $X_{(\lfloor \alpha N\rfloor)}$ is an non-decreasing sequence, we have that $X_{(\lfloor \alpha N\rfloor)}\xrightarrow{a.s.}F^{-1}(\alpha)$